# the urlib2.URLError and its reason in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2

The title of the question may be a bit confusing but I don't really know how best to word it...
I've found the following chunk of code which downloads a web page from the web by making use of the urllib2 library.

```
import urllib2

def download(url):
    try:
        html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    except urllib2.URLError as e:
        print 'Download error:', e.reason
        html = None
    return html
```

Now if it happens that `e.code` is 404 then `e.reason` is simply an empty string which means it bears absolutely no information on what triggered the error, thus I don't really understand the point of using `e.reason` here. 
It seems like it would be more reasonable to print `e` instead but even if I change it to simply `print e` it will still yield something awkward: `HTTP Error 404:` and the colon is apparenty followed by an empty string...
So it appears to me that the abovementioned code is a little clumsy in terms of exception handling. Is it so?

Comment: Yes, simply `print e` would be better.  More usual would be to not capture the exception at all, since it doesn't seem to be handled.  What is the question, exactly?

Comment: 404 means that the requested resource was not found. Better to `print e` for further details.

Comment: @wim well I took this piece of code from a book and was a bit perplexed by the way the exception is handled there so I thought perhaps I was missing something...

Comment: @ichbinblau yeah i know that, but for some reason the author decided on using `e.reason` which somewhat perplexed me.

Comment: Another way is to try the url link in your browser and see what would happen. At least to ensure the url would return content.

Comment: @ichbinblau exactly, I was just trying to understand why the author put it this way...I mean why he used `e.reason` when it would be probably more reasonable to print e.

Comment: @weeCoder A ‘reason’ attribute is a tuple containing an error code and a text error message for URLError. (https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/urllib2.html#urlerror) from its document. I guess it should work like that but may not work correctly.

Comment: @ichbinblau I see now, after trying for some more, I figured that it doesn't always return what it is supposd to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem that you could either use the error itself (print e) or the code and the reason (print "Download Error: ", e.code, e.reason) if you wanted to see the 404 code.

Comment: seems so, I think the message (if it's there) must be informative which means that empty strings should not be allowed. I think it's just common sense.